# Why ScrollTop is always 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know what is scrollTop and using **jQuery**. But, it's always showing 0.

here is my **jQuery** code:

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()

//onscroll
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    console.log(scrollTop);
}
```

If need, I can also add **HTML** and **CSS** codes.

I try to use **JavaScript**:

```
var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;

//onscroll
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    console.log(scrollTop);
}
```

But, same.

If answer isn't writed in **jQuery** it's better.

Comment: The better question is, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is because the variable does not keep on updating... It reads the value at that moment in time and that is what it will remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of scrollTop is not being updated dynamically in the onscroll event handler. Instead, it is only assigned once when the script is initially run.
Maybe this?

Using jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log(scrollTop);
});
```

Plain JS:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  console.log(scrollTop);
});
```

Comment: Avoid using on* handlers (like the one you suggested: `onscroll`) in JS. Use addEventListener instead.

Comment: Noted, thanks.. updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

`scrollTop` will initially get set to 0, then every time you log it, it's going to use that value.

If you want a new value for `scrollTop`, it needs to be recalculated. Put the calculation inside of your function bound to `window.onscroll`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `scrollTop` variable is initialized but it is not updated inside the `onscroll` function, that's why it remains unchanged. Explanation: your `onscroll` function is called each time you move your cursor, and its state (positions:`e.pageY`) is stored in the variable `e` of your `onscroll` function.

Here is a way to get the cursor/pointer position onScroll using jQuery:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
  var current_position_from_top = e.pageY;
  console.log('Vertical position in pixel:', current_position_from_top);
});
```